# Windows 11 keeps switching to High Performance power plan

Tags: windows, power-management

I have a Windows 11 desktop that seems to randomly switch to the High Performance power plan.  I will switch it back to to Balanced, but it switches back to High for no obvious reason.  How can I figure out what is doing this.  I dont see anything in the log - plus I dont notice if for a long while anyways.

Comment: Update any available power plans, possibly update UEFI BIOS (vendor updater), restart and reset the power plan to default.  This often works for me, so may be worth your consideration.

Comment: If it’s a desktop, why are you switching it to Balanced mode, typically that’s only used on laptops?

Comment: My own Desktop Windows 11 Pro uses the Balanced Plan. Lenovo uses this for most defaults and it has worked well for me

Comment: @Ramhound because the balanced will actually suspend the machine when not used.  I could change what high performance does, but thats a fix for the symptom, not a solution to the problem.